# unity3d detect gameobject enters in main camera screen and leaves

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking for events or a code that will give me information that gameobject entered in the main camera screen and then leaves the screen so i can destroy it.

What i'm doing is a top down game which is moving forward all the time... some objects are spawned far away so i want them to move when they enter in the game screen and after leaving the screen destroy them.

i tried this event but it's triggered before game object enters in the screen... i saw some comments that rendering engine is triggering this event for shadow rendering bla bla... 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html

Comment: OnBecameVisible is less reliable in the IDE due to the fact you have a dev camera involved in the scene.  It should be reliable in the game itself.

Comment: Let the scene window in editor inactive

Answer (score 1):

On top of `OnBecomeVisible` you also have other options such as `OnWillRenderObject, Renderer.isVisible`
You can also calculate whether an object's bounding box falls within the camera's view frustum, using [GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html)